# Find the specific number using regex python near particular word

Tags: python-3.x

I have array of patterns like keywords

```
patterns = [reference number, Ref:, Invoice:, Sales Quote No:]

Sentence 1: My document reference number 25XPOI9876 which is entered
Sentence 2: Sales Quote No: SP21-SQ10452 entered quote number
Sentence 3: Ref:9874621kl is attached:
```

Is there any solution to get the the output:

1. 25XPOI9876
2. SP21-SQ10452
3. 9874621kl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Regex,

Captures only `25XPOI9876`, `SP21-SQ10452`, `9874621kl`

`(?:(?<=reference number )|(?<=Ref:)|(?<=Invoice:)|(?<=Sales Quote No: ))[\w\d-]+`

**Output:**

[image]

[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/iXenxF/2)

Sample code in Python:

```py
import re

a = '''Sentence 1: My document reference number 25XPOI9876 which is entered
Sentence 2: Sales Quote No: SP21-SQ10452 entered quote number
Sentence 3: Ref:9874621kl is attached:'''

print(re.findall(r'(?:(?<=reference number )|(?<=Ref:)|(?<=Invoice:)|(?<=Sales Quote No: ))[\w\d-]+', a))
```

Outputs:

```
['25XPOI9876', 'SP21-SQ10452', '9874621kl']
```

tell me if its okay for you...